# Python 3 json.load() reads JSON file in wrong order

Tags: json, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, raspberry-pi3

When I try to load a JSON file with json.load() the file gets read in wrong order, and then saved in wrong order with json.dump()

JSON file:

```
{
"val0": 1386.9633674001711,
"val1": 0.0,
"val2": 0.021159999999999957,
"val3": 2.6119050462121836,
"val4": 0.0
}
```

How Python reads it:

```
{"val1","val4","val0","val2","val3"}
```

How can I combat this? I'm using a RasPi for this now, and on Windows it worked perfectly fine with just json.load(), no wrong order there

Comment: dictionaries are unordered both in json and python. You can find some solutions using python's `OrderedDict` but this only goes so far because its an informal hack and not supported generally by json parsers. Does it matter that the order changes?

Comment: yes it does sadly, will try the OrderedDict. But it's kinda curios that it works on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order is a must you can load it directly into python's `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
j = json.load(jsonFile, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Comment: Thank you, not exactly what I was hoping for but now it works on the RasPi too.